# Workload Scheduler: cannot run CLI commands on agents without root priviliges on UNIX workstations

Tags: workload-scheduler

I have installed a number of agents as non-root on a series of UNIX workstations, but I cannot run any command-line commands on them. Whenever I try to run any composer or conman commands, all I get is a core dump.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried setting the env variables? Run the `". ./tws_env.sh"` script before running any CLIs.